Fastlane release_notes: An attribute value is invalid. - The language specified is not listed for localization
When uploading an app to app store connect using Fastlane I have defined function like this:
  upload_to_app_store(
    skip_screenshots: true,
    force: true,
    run_precheck_before_submit: false,
    ipa: options[:ipa_path],
    release_notes: {
      'pl-PL' => 'Naprawa drobnych błędów i poprawa działania aplikacji.',
      'uk-UK' => 'Ремонт незначних помилок та покращення операції застосування.'
    }
  )

But console prints the following error:

An attribute value is invalid. - The language specified is not listed for localization - /data/attributes/locale

Where is the list of available languages for localizations here?

I have found an answer here:
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_app_store/
Available language codes
ar-SA, ca, cs, da, de-DE, el, en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-US, es-ES, es-MX, fi, fr-CA, fr-FR, he, hi, hr, hu, id, it, ja, ko, ms, nl-NL, no, pl, pt-BR, pt-PT, ro, ru, sk, sv, th, tr, uk, vi, zh-Hans, zh-Hant

